# Allocation failed for NV6 Promo on Azure

Tags: azure, nvidia

Early this afternoon, I tried starting one of my NV6 Promo VMs I've had for a while, and I get a random error "Allocation failed."

Does anyone know why I could be getting this error? I have been using NV6 for quite some time with no allocation issues, so it's odd to get an error message randomly right now.

Here is the full error message:

"Allocation failed. We do not have sufficient capacity for the requested VM size in this region. Read more about improving likelihood of allocation success at http://aka.ms/allocation-guidance (Code: AllocationFailed)"

Comment: I'm wondering if you actually read the message and the linked article? It seems pretty clear to me what the problem is and how to temporarily work around it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear, there is not enough capacity in that region to allocate  you a VM of the size requested. Your options are to try another region, or wait.